# How to choice specific range ( using redshift regex )

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I'm trying a regular expression to extract only numbers between letters or special characters.

I have an amazon-redshift environment and am using the regexp_substr function to solve the problem, but it doesn't work so well.

My table

```
+------------------------+
 |    text                |
 +------------------------+
 | abc:1+550(name)        |
 | abc:1+1100(name)       |
 | abc:1+512(name)        |
 | abc:1+2932(name)       |
 +------------------------+
```

My code
regexp_substr(a.text,'^+[\d]($')  <- but, not work.

I've never learned regular expressions properly and I can't solve it myself by referring to the related documents.

Expected table

```
+------------------------+
 |    text                |
 +------------------------+
 | 550                    |
 | 1100                   |
 | 512                    |
 | 2932                   |
 +------------------------+
```

Comment: Please show us your existing attempt.

Comment: well... I'm trying to find a rule for picking numbers after the + character and before the parentheses. But it doesn't work as well as I thought.
e.g) regexp_substr(a.text, "^\+[\d]\($")

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under the question to add any additional information to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
select replace(regexp_substr(col, '[0-9]+[(]'), '(', '')
```

Comment: Works fine!! I tried to pull it out at once using regexp_substr. Thank you for letting me know how.